# invalid request when URL rewriting in web2py

Tags: python, url-rewriting, web2py

I'm learning web2py and I'm very happy with this framework, but I have a problem setting up nice urls. I want to transform:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/computers/default/computer/this-is-a-test
```

into:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/computer/this-is-a-test
```

I have put this in routes.py but I get an invalid request:

```
default_application = 'computers' 
default_controller = 'default' 
default_function = 'index'  

routes_in = ( ('/computer/$1', '/computers/default/computer/$1'), )

routes_out = ( ('/computers/default/computer/$1', '/computer/$1'), )
```

Any idea? I have been some hours looking for examples and documentation but nothing works. I like web2py very much but this is essential for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use autoroutes, take a look at autoroutes on web2py scripts folder

http://snipt.net/rochacbruno/routesconf/ and /routespy/

Answer (score 1):

Change your $1's to $a's.

These are treated specially by web2py's rewrite parser, but must be alpha.